# Regex "Not starting 'C'" case insensitive?

Tags: regex

Can someone help me out with a single line regex for this?

Currently using:

```
^(?!C).*
```

But need an alternative as it won't work with my system.

Cheers!

Comment: How about `^[^cC].*`?

Comment: `^[^Cc].*` to make it case insensitive

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: Just a system written in Java

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
^(?i)[^c].*
```

`(?i)` stands for case insensitive, but you can use this instead:

```
^[^cC].*
```

or in javascript style:

```
/^[^c].*/i
```

Answer (score 0):

This could suit your needs:

```
^(?:[^cC].*)?$
```

This will match empty strings (due to the `(?:...)?` part) or strings not beginning with `c` nor `C`.